# Drawing with a mouse and the voice

Tags: processing

I'm trying to make a "Drawing Challenge": draw with the mouse for the Y-point and with the voice for the X-point. I tried this

```
import ddf.minim.*;

Minim minim;
AudioInput in;

float volume;
float moyenne=0;
int tampon=5;



void setup() {
  size(640, 640, P2D);

  minim = new Minim(this);
  minim.debugOn();
  background(255);

 // get a line in from Minim, default bit depth is 16
 in = minim.getLineIn(Minim.STEREO, 1024);
}

void draw() {

  volume = in.mix.level()*10;
  moyenne=((moyenne * tampon) + volume)/(tampon+3);
   if ( volume > 1){
    //line(15, 90, 95, 10);
    line(moyenne, mouseY, moyenne, pmouseY);
      if(keyPressed == true ){
        stroke( random(255), random(255), random(255), random(255));
      }
    println(moyenne);
  }
}


void stop() {
 // always close Minim audio classes when you are done with them
 in.close();
 minim.stop();

 super.stop();
```

This is not sensitive enough to receive the sound from the microphone or just trace some vertical lines without fluidity.
My question is :  How can I make it more fluid while increasing the reception sensitivity of the microphone sound ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I forgot my question ._.

How can I make it more fluid while increasing the reception sensitivity of the microphone sound?